# PHP content of session variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to pass a value between 2 pages through a `$_SESSION` variable then empty it as follows:

I'm assigning the session variable with a value on one PHP page:

```
$_SESSION["elementName"]="a_373";
```

And trying to store it in a variable on another page as follows:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION["elementName"])) {
    $elemName=$_SESSION["elementName"];
    $_SESSION["elementName"]="";
} else {
    $elemName="";
}
```

The value of `$elemName` is always empty when I print it out. However, I get the correct printout when I remove the `$_SESSION["elementName"]="";` line from the above code.

Edit: I'm printing `$elemName` and not `$_SESSION["elementName"]` - `print($elemName);`

I'm on a shared hosting account with PHP 5.3.2 and `register_globals` set to off (as per `phpinfo();`).

I need to reset/empty the session variable once I get the value it has, but it's not working and this has been baffling me for the last couple of days. Any ideas why? Thanks!

EDIT:

Additional clues: I tested with the session's var_dump before the if statement and set another value for $elemName in the else section as follows:

```
var_dump($_SESSION["elementName"]);

$elemName="x";

if (isset($_SESSION["elementName"]) && !empty($_SESSION["elementName"])) {
    $elemName=$_SESSION["elementName"];
    $_SESSION["elementName"]="";
} else {
    $elemName="None";
}

print("<br />".$elemName);
```

I got this result:

```
string(5) "a_373"
None
```

Comment: please check if you have a session_start() before any other output

Comment: if it works when $_SESSION["elementName"]=""; is removed, then it is not it.

Comment: sorry, missed that line :(

Comment: Have you declared $elemName above the if statement? In other words, is the scope correct?

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. In file 1 i have: `session_start();
$_SESSION["elementName"]="a_373";` and in file 2 i have `$elemName;
if (!empty($_SESSION["elementName"])) {
    $elemName=$_SESSION["elementName"];
    $_SESSION["elementName"]="";
} else {
    $elemName="";
}

echo $elemName;` Can you try it out? Visit file1 and then file2.

Comment: @rubelet, I tried them again and still the same blank result. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isset($_SESSION["elementName"])` and `unset($_SESSION["elementName"])` instead.

Comment: Thanks Juampi, but it gives the same result. Actually I tried `unset` before trying with assigning an empty string to it with no luck.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help! I'm sure someone will come up with a solution.

Comment: are you sure page is not refresh before you use variable again? if it does ,then variable would be lost.

Comment: Yes Bojan, the page is not refreshing it's just loading once.

Comment: Yes, immediately after the condition.

Comment: I'm getting this notice when I unset the session variable instead: `Notice:  Undefined variable: elemName in ...`

Comment: Just to be sure, did you start the session?

Comment: Yes Juampi, I have `session_start();` at the top of both pages (and I have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to spit out all errors)

Comment: I really don't know what else to tell you, but you may want to check my other answer just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing out `$elemName`? If yes than there shouldn't be any blank output *unless and until your `else` condition returns true*, but if you are printing `$_SESSION["elementName"]` than you'll get no output as you are making it blank

```
$_SESSION["elementName"]="";
```

Correct way to remove a session var completely is to use `unset($_SESSION["elementName"])`

Though if you want to make it empty, `== ''` is enough

Also be cautious while using `unset()` because after you unset the session and later use that index to print, it will show you undefined index error.

Update(As @nvanesch Commented)

> I guess your `else` condition is getting satisfied, because you are
>   using `$elemName="";` in your else, thus you are not returned with any
>   output

Also `if (!empty($_SESSION["elementName"])) {` will return false if you are not using `session_start()` at the very top of your page

Comment: i guess because Nino Kay specifically notes that he prints out $elemName. Not my -1 btw

Answer (score 0):

Check the Below code and test it

```
if (isset($_SESSION["elementName"]) && $_SESSION["elementName"]!="") {
    $elemName=$_SESSION["elementName"];
    $_SESSION["elementName"]="";
} else {
    $elemName="";
}
```

Empty only check value is empty or not, But by isset we can check varaible exit and does not content empty value

Answer (score 0):

I once created this class in order to be able to have this ability, and it works wonderfully:

```
<?php

class Flash {

    public function set($key, $message) {
        $_SESSION["flash_$key"] = $message;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        $message = $_SESSION["flash_$key"];
        unset($_SESSION["flash_$key"]);
        return $message;
    }

    public function has($key) {
        return isset($_SESSION["flash_$key"]);
    }

}
```

It's pretty similar to what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but you may want to give it a try. You obviously need to have the session already started.